# Position of sprite

Tags: c#, xna

```
        Vector2 drawPos = (-screenPosition);
        drawPos.X *= (float)device.DisplayMode.Width;
        drawPos.Y *= (float)device.DisplayMode.Height;

        spriteBatch.Draw(
            texture, 
            drawPos, 
            getRectangle(), 
            Color.White, 
            rotation, 
            getOrigin(), 
            1.0f / zoom, 
            SpriteEffects.None, 
            0);
```

I have a drawPos essentialy being 0..1 and multiply that with the display width and height. screenposition is obtained by dragging the screen. With other elements, primitives, the position is correct and is exactly being dragged along with the input. However when drawing a sprite the sprite is moving to quickly, faster than the input, giving a sort of parallax effect, not what I want.

I somehow get the feeling I am using the parameters wrong, and spriteBatch.Draw(..) does not need pixelcoordinates..

Width and height is obtained by texture loader.

```
    public Vector2 getOrigin()
    {
        return new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
        return new Rectangle(
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height);
    }
```

Also, I am developing for Windows Phone.

Comment: Need some more info, do you mean the game window that's being dragged? How is screenPosition defined? Use viewport properties for height/width: graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width/Height.

Answer (score 1):

The `getRectangle()` method is basically useless, you are specifying a source rectangle which is the same size as the texture - use `null` instead (unless ofcourse you've just simplified your code for us).

How is screenPosition defined? I don't understand why you'd times it by -1. You are also using the screen that the window is on to get width/height with `device.DisplayMode` which is something you should avoid because this will only work when your window is the same size as the screen.

Try drawing the sprite to `Vector2.Zero` without an origin, and with the `sourceRectangle` set to `null`. Slowly add back in your other parameters and see where the error is occuring. Can't really say much else without more information!

```
spriteBatch.Draw(
    texture,
    Vector2.Zero,
    null,
    Color.White,
    0,
    Vector2.Zero,
    1,
    SpriteEffects.None,
    1);
```

This is what I would use to make sure the sprite is actually displaying properly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, pretty helpful, but I have already solved it by switching width and height. Probably needed that because I am using landscape mode.

Comment: What you mean by that? If swapping the height and width fixes then it sounds like your actually calculations are the wrong way round!